# Probability in the Multiverse Interpretation of Quantum Mechanics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, soft-question, probability, quantum-interpretations, multiverse

The Multiverse Interpretation of Quantum Mechanics interprets a quantum decision as different universes, each with each outcome. I was wondering how probability plays into this. For example, if we have some hypothetical particle that we somehow has a 60% chance of measuring spin up on, when we measure its spin, would there be a 60% probability that we are in the universe in which the measurement’s result is up, or would it be something else? Please explain.

Comment: I've had this question, as well. If the spin-up universe and the spin-down universe are equally real, how does the difference in probability manifest?